# Comments expand/collapse is not working with comments view more/less

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
var commentCount = $('.review-history-comment').length;
$('.total-count').html(commentCount);

var commentsCountLi = $('#myList').children("li").length;
if (commentsCountLi <= 0) {
  $('#myList').parent('.request-action-info').addClass('no-history');
}

var ul = $('#myList'), ulh = ul.height(), h = 0;

ul.children('li').each(function(i) {
  if(i===4) {
      return false;
  }
  h += this.offsetHeight;        
});

$(".review-history-comment-icons").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass("icon-rotate");
  $(this).next(".review-history-comment-desc").toggle();        
  if ("$('#myList'):hasClass(.myList-overflow)") {
    $("#myList").removeClass("myList-overflow");           
  }
  if ($(".review-history-comment-desc").is(':visible')) {
    $("#myList").removeClass("myList-overflow");
      $('#myList-toggle').text("View Less -");
      if ($('#myList-toggle').text("View Less -")) {
        $("#myList").removeClass("myList-overflow");
      }
  }
  else if ($(".review-history-comment-desc").is(':hidden')){
    $("#myList").addClass("myList-overflow");
    $('#myList-toggle').text("View More +");
  }
});

ul.css({'height':h+'px'});
$('#myList-toggle').click(function() {
  ul.animate({'height':(ul.height()>h?h:ulh)+'px'});
  ($(this).text() === "View More +") ? $(this).text("View Less -") : $(this).text("View More +");
  $("#myList").toggleClass("myList-overflow");
  return false;
});
```

```css
.align-right {
  float: right;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

/* line 49, ../sass/base.scss */
.align-left {
  float: left;
}
/* Request Action */
/* line 25, ../sass/request-details.scss */
.request-action {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

/* line 28, ../sass/request-details.scss */
.request-action-header {
  background: #5D5D5D;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

/* line 36, ../sass/request-details.scss */
.request-action-form {
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 20px;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
}

/* line 43, ../sass/request-details.scss */
.request-action-form .request-action-form-area {
  background: #EEE;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* line 48, ../sass/request-details.scss */
.request-action-form form .button {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

/* line 51, ../sass/request-details.scss */
.request-action-info {
  max-height: 310px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-height: 310px;
  background: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

/* line 59, ../sass/request-details.scss */
.no-history {
  background: #FFF url("../images/no-history.png") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: 242px 130px;
}

/* Review History */
/* line 65, ../sass/request-details.scss */
.review-history-comment {
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
}

/* line 72, ../sass/request-details.scss */
.review-history-comment .comment-type {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #474747;
}

/* line 77, ../sass/request-details.scss */
.review-history-comment .comment-history {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 15px;
}

/* line 81, ../sass/request-details.scss */
.review-history-comment .comment-history.approved {
  color: #4E8A0B;
}

/* line 84, ../sass/request-details.scss */
.comment-by a, .comment-date {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* line 90, ../sass/request-details.scss */
.review-history-comment-data {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

/* line 93, ../sass/request-details.scss */
.myList-overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* line 96, ../sass/request-details.scss */
.review-history-comment-desc {
  display: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  word-break: break-all;
  position: relative;
}

.show-comments {
  display: block;
}

/* line 103, ../sass/request-details.scss */
.review-history-comment-icons.icon-rotate i {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  position: relative;
  top: 14px;
  right: -3px;
}

/* line 109, ../sass/request-details.scss */
.review-history-comment-icons:hover {
  cursor: hand;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* line 113, ../sass/request-details.scss */
.review-history-comment-icons i {
  color: #048EC2;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

/* line 121, ../sass/request-details.scss */
.review-history-comment-footer {
  background: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #9B9B9B;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="request-action">
  <h4 class="request-action-header">Review History</h4>
  <div class="request-action-info">
    <ul id="myList" class="myList-overflow">
      <li>
        <div class="review-history-comment">
          <div class="review-history-comment-icons align-left">
            <i class="fa fa-check fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-user-circle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="review-history-comment-data align-left">
            <span class="comment-type">OCO Clearance: </span><span class="comment-history approved">Approved</span>
            <br>
            <span class="comment-by"><a href="#">Kunal Vijan</a></span><span class="comment-date">12/22/2016</span>
          </div>
          <div class="review-history-comment-icons text-right icon-rotate">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="review-history-comment-desc clear">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="review-history-comment">
          <div class="review-history-comment-icons align-left">
            <i class="fa fa-commenting fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-user-circle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="review-history-comment-data align-left">
            <span class="comment-type">Referral Comment </span>
            <br>
            <span class="comment-by"><a href="#">Kunal Vijan</a></span><span class="comment-date">12/22/2016</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="review-history-comment">
          <div class="review-history-comment-icons align-left">
            <i class="fa fa-check fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-user-circle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="review-history-comment-data align-left">
            <span class="comment-type">OCO Clearance: </span><span class="comment-history approved">Approved</span>
            <br>
            <span class="comment-by"><a href="#">Kunal Vijan</a></span><span class="comment-date">12/22/2016</span>
          </div>
          <div class="review-history-comment-icons text-right icon-rotate">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="review-history-comment-desc clear">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="review-history-comment">
          <div class="review-history-comment-icons align-left">
            <i class="fa fa-commenting fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-user-circle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="review-history-comment-data align-left">
            <span class="comment-type">Referral Comment </span>
            <br>
            <span class="comment-by"><a href="#">Kunal Vijan</a></span><span class="comment-date">12/22/2016</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="review-history-comment">
          <div class="review-history-comment-icons align-left">
            <i class="fa fa-check fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-user-circle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="review-history-comment-data align-left">
            <span class="comment-type">OCO Clearance: </span><span class="comment-history approved">Approved</span>
            <br>
            <span class="comment-by"><a href="#">Kunal Vijan</a></span><span class="comment-date">12/22/2016</span>
          </div>
          <div class="review-history-comment-icons text-right icon-rotate">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="review-history-comment-desc clear">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="review-history-comment">
          <div class="review-history-comment-icons align-left">
            <i class="fa fa-commenting fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-user-circle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="review-history-comment-data align-left">
            <span class="comment-type">Referral Comment </span>
            <br>
            <span class="comment-by"><a href="#">Kunal Vijan</a></span><span class="comment-date">12/22/2016</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="review-history-comment-footer">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">                                    
      Total Comments: <span class="total-count"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
      <a href="#" id="myList-toggle">View More +</a>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

When a user clicks on expand any comments (the arrow at the right of oco clearance), the bottom text is changing to "view less".

But, at the same time, when I try to run view more/less script, It fails.
View/less should change to view more and remove the overflow scrollbar, but doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your `click` handler to avoid using `toggleClass` because you use `addClass` and `removeClass` on the comment expand arrows.

So if the `myList-overflow` class was already removed from `#myList`via an expand arrow, `toggleClass` will put it back and this is the problem.

I also precised the icon rotation selector these arrow in script, since the checkmarks were also rotating!

;)

```js
    var commentCount = $('.review-history-comment').length;
    $('.total-count').html(commentCount);

    var commentsCountLi = $('#myList').children("li").length;
    if (commentsCountLi <= 0) {
      $('#myList').parent('.request-action-info').addClass('no-history');
    }

    var ul = $('#myList'), ulh = ul.height(), h = 0;

    ul.children('li').each(function(i) {
      if(i===4) {
          return false;
      }
      h += this.offsetHeight;        
    });

    $(".review-history-comment-icons.text-right").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).toggleClass("icon-rotate");
      $(this).next(".review-history-comment-desc").toggle();        
      if ("$('#myList'):hasClass(.myList-overflow)") {
        $("#myList").removeClass("myList-overflow");           
      }
      if ($(".review-history-comment-desc").is(':visible')) {
        $("#myList").removeClass("myList-overflow");
          $('#myList-toggle').text("View Less -");
          if ($('#myList-toggle').text("View Less -")) {
            $("#myList").removeClass("myList-overflow");
          }
      }
      else if ($(".review-history-comment-desc").is(':hidden')){
        $("#myList").addClass("myList-overflow");
        ul.animate({'height':h+'px'});
        $('#myList-toggle').text("View More +");
      }
    });

    // =========================================== HERE ARE ALL CHANGES
    ul.css({'height':h+'px'});
    $('#myList-toggle').click(function() {
    
      if($(this).text() === "View More +"){
        $(this).text("View Less -")
        $("#myList").removeClass("myList-overflow");
        ul.animate({'height':ulh+'px'});
      }else{
        $(this).text("View More +");
        $("#myList").addClass("myList-overflow");
        $(".review-history-comment-desc").hide();
        $(".review-history-comment-icons.text-right").addClass("icon-rotate");
        ul.animate({'height':h+'px'});
      }
      // ===========================================
      return false;
    });
```

```css
.align-right {
      float: right;
    }

    ol, ul {
      list-style: none;
    }

    .clear {
      clear: both;
    }

    /* line 49, ../sass/base.scss */
    .align-left {
      float: left;
    }
    /* Request Action */
    /* line 25, ../sass/request-details.scss */
    .request-action {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }

    /* line 28, ../sass/request-details.scss */
    .request-action-header {
      background: #5D5D5D;
      color: #FFF;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: normal;
    }

    /* line 36, ../sass/request-details.scss */
    .request-action-form {
      background: #FFF;
      padding: 20px;
      border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
    }

    /* line 43, ../sass/request-details.scss */
    .request-action-form .request-action-form-area {
      background: #EEE;
      padding: 20px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    /* line 48, ../sass/request-details.scss */
    .request-action-form form .button {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }

    /* line 51, ../sass/request-details.scss */
    .request-action-info {
      max-height: 310px;
      overflow-y: auto;
      min-height: 310px;
      background: #FFF;
      border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
      border-bottom: 0;
    }

    /* line 59, ../sass/request-details.scss */
    .no-history {
      background: #FFF url("../images/no-history.png") center center no-repeat;
      background-size: 242px 130px;
    }

    /* Review History */
    /* line 65, ../sass/request-details.scss */
    .review-history-comment {
      background: #FFF;
      padding: 15px 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
      border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
    }

    /* line 72, ../sass/request-details.scss */
    .review-history-comment .comment-type {
      font-weight: 600;
      font-size: 15px;
      color: #474747;
    }

    /* line 77, ../sass/request-details.scss */
    .review-history-comment .comment-history {
      font-weight: 600;
      font-size: 15px;
    }

    /* line 81, ../sass/request-details.scss */
    .review-history-comment .comment-history.approved {
      color: #4E8A0B;
    }

    /* line 84, ../sass/request-details.scss */
    .comment-by a, .comment-date {
      font-size: 12px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      margin-top: 5px;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    /* line 90, ../sass/request-details.scss */
    .review-history-comment-data {
      margin-left: 10px;
    }

    /* line 93, ../sass/request-details.scss */
    .myList-overflow {
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    /* line 96, ../sass/request-details.scss */
    .review-history-comment-desc {
      display: none;
      padding-top: 10px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      word-break: break-all;
      position: relative;
    }

    .show-comments {
      display: block;
    }

    /* line 103, ../sass/request-details.scss */
    .review-history-comment-icons.icon-rotate i {
      transform: rotate(-180deg);
      position: relative;
      top: 14px;
      right: -3px;
    }

    /* line 109, ../sass/request-details.scss */
    .review-history-comment-icons:hover {
      cursor: hand;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    /* line 113, ../sass/request-details.scss */
    .review-history-comment-icons i {
      color: #048EC2;
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      font-size: 22px;
      padding: 5px;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }

    /* line 121, ../sass/request-details.scss */
    .review-history-comment-footer {
      background: #FFF;
      border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
      border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 600;
      color: #9B9B9B;
      padding: 15px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="request-action">
      <h4 class="request-action-header">Review History</h4>
      <div class="request-action-info">
        <ul id="myList" class="myList-overflow">
          <li>
            <div class="review-history-comment">
              <div class="review-history-comment-icons align-left">
                <i class="fa fa-check fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-user-circle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="review-history-comment-data align-left">
                <span class="comment-type">OCO Clearance: </span><span class="comment-history approved">Approved</span>
                <br>
                <span class="comment-by"><a href="#">Kunal Vijan</a></span><span class="comment-date">12/22/2016</span>
              </div>
              <div class="review-history-comment-icons text-right icon-rotate">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="review-history-comment-desc clear">
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="review-history-comment">
              <div class="review-history-comment-icons align-left">
                <i class="fa fa-commenting fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-user-circle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="review-history-comment-data align-left">
                <span class="comment-type">Referral Comment </span>
                <br>
                <span class="comment-by"><a href="#">Kunal Vijan</a></span><span class="comment-date">12/22/2016</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="review-history-comment">
              <div class="review-history-comment-icons align-left">
                <i class="fa fa-check fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-user-circle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="review-history-comment-data align-left">
                <span class="comment-type">OCO Clearance: </span><span class="comment-history approved">Approved</span>
                <br>
                <span class="comment-by"><a href="#">Kunal Vijan</a></span><span class="comment-date">12/22/2016</span>
              </div>
              <div class="review-history-comment-icons text-right icon-rotate">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="review-history-comment-desc clear">
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="review-history-comment">
              <div class="review-history-comment-icons align-left">
                <i class="fa fa-commenting fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-user-circle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="review-history-comment-data align-left">
                <span class="comment-type">Referral Comment </span>
                <br>
                <span class="comment-by"><a href="#">Kunal Vijan</a></span><span class="comment-date">12/22/2016</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="review-history-comment">
              <div class="review-history-comment-icons align-left">
                <i class="fa fa-check fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-user-circle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="review-history-comment-data align-left">
                <span class="comment-type">OCO Clearance: </span><span class="comment-history approved">Approved</span>
                <br>
                <span class="comment-by"><a href="#">Kunal Vijan</a></span><span class="comment-date">12/22/2016</span>
              </div>
              <div class="review-history-comment-icons text-right icon-rotate">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="review-history-comment-desc clear">
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="review-history-comment">
              <div class="review-history-comment-icons align-left">
                <i class="fa fa-commenting fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-user-circle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="review-history-comment-data align-left">
                <span class="comment-type">Referral Comment </span>
                <br>
                <span class="comment-by"><a href="#">Kunal Vijan</a></span><span class="comment-date">12/22/2016</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="review-history-comment-footer">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">                                    
          Total Comments: <span class="total-count"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
          <a href="#" id="myList-toggle">View More +</a>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I can still see one issue when user will click on view more first and then expand any comment, text will change to view less. again once you collpase the comment text will click on view more it should also remove the scroll bar n hide other li's

Comment: I see. I fixed this. Have a look a edit history for the changes. ;)